# Playing with CSS Opacity

Tags: css, opacity

I am trying to create a buttonbar using simple `<div>` and change its opacity to 50% and give a background

But the elements which come inside this division exhibit the same transparency as there parent `<div>`. I want them to retain 100% opacity. (Which is not possible). How to make this Possible?

A sample CSS of what I am trying to do is this

```
<style>    
    #bar { background:#09f;opacity:0.5; }
    #bar a { background:#FF0;opacity:1; }
</style>
<div id="bar">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <a href="#">Feedback</a> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the [`rgba`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgba-color) property for that, since opacity affects all children.

```
#bar { background: rgba(0, 120, 255, 0.5); }
```

Chris Coyier (CSS-tricks) has written a post about this: http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

Comment: Best possible answer with the RGBA 4th Param :) +1

Comment: But this is not IE Compatible

Comment: @Starx neither is `opacity` Do as @RobertPitt says, include the `rgba` as a secondary parameter, so you have a fall-back for IE. If you want a more cross-browser compatible solution, use oezi's answer: transparent png (won't work in IE6, though), which isn't as fluid as using only CSS, but will work with IE7+.

Answer (score 1):

if you want only the background to be opaque, you could use a transparent png or an rgba-value as background. otherwise this isn't possible (as you mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

Set the opacity in your *graphics editor* and flatten the two layers together.

You can also [add another element](http://reisio.com/temp/punkid/).

(You should also be using [a list](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/).)